# How to center a tkinter widget, ignoring another widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've a three widgets in tkinter with Python 3. One picture (as a label) and two labels. I want the picture to be at the left of a frame, all the way. Then, I want the two labels to be centered across the X-axis, basically ignoring the picture and then centering. The first label needs to go above the second label. How can I achieve this? I've been trying a long time now and I just can't get the ignoring of the picture down.

EDIT: Thanks to DerrickTSE (not sarcastic), I can explain it a little bit better. I did ment the GUI to look like this:

```
-----------
|         |                             Label 1
|   Pic   |                             -------
|         |                             Label 2
-----------
```

Where Label 1 & Label 2 are ment to be centered.

Comment: I kinda solved this problem by using the place geometry manager for the picture, which now is independent, because it's place is fixed. But, I'm still interested in only using the grid or pack geometry manager.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want to organize your UI. So I am assuming you want to achieve something like this:

```
-----------
|         |  Label 1
|   Pic   |  -------
|         |  Label 2
-----------
```

Then you can use `grid` property to organize your widgets. To implement, you can call `rowspan` in method `.grid()` to extend specific cell. Thus, brief code should look like this:

```
pic = tk.Label(frame,...)
pic.grid(column = 0, rowspan = 2) # extend the cell by 2 rows

Label1 = tk.Label(frame,...)
Label1.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

Label2 = tk.Label(frame,...)
Label2.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
```

For more tkinter grid instruction: [Doc](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I edited my question to kinda anwer your answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? The window can expand and the labels will sit at center.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

pic = """
-----------
|         |
|   Pic   |
|         |
-----------
"""

p = tk.Label(root,text=pic,font="Consolas 8")
p.pack(side="left")

f = tk.Frame(root)

tk.Label(f,text="Label 1").pack()
tk.Label(f,text="-------").pack()
tk.Label(f,text="Label 2").pack()

f.pack(side="left",expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, that is what I want to achieve, but if you look closely the labels (label1 and label2) are not centred horizontally.